# Bind element if css class exists

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a group of 3 bootstrap styled [checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-usage) like so:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind=""><input type="checkbox">Checkbox 1</label>
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2</label>
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><input type="checkbox">Checkbox 3</label>
</div>
```

At runtime if the first checkbox is pressed, when I inspect the element it gets an `active` css class appended to it:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" >
```

How should my `data-bind=""` property look like if I want a function to execute when the input receives the `active` class? I would also want the opposite to happen as well. When the active class is no longer present, a function must also be called.

I can't use a click binding on the checkbox because it doesn't work because of bootstrap's way of "ticking" a checkbox.

Thank you (demo - http://jsfiddle.net/H7Js6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knockout is about having a viewmodel that represents your UI. Instead of a `click` binding, you can have `checked` binding and use the `subscribe` function:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: cb1" />Checkbox 1
</label>
```

And in the js:

```
var viewmodel = function () {
    this.cb1 = ko.observable();
    this.cb1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        //your code here gets called every time the checked status changes
        // use newValue to know the new state
    });
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/A4BnD/)

## Update

Thank you for your fiddle, it always helps to have one.

Indeed, in this case the checked is not changed when the bootstrap css is loaded (if you remove the resource, you'll see it works).

To workaround it, you can have a custom binding handler that will check the presence of the css class for you:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapCheckbox = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel, 
                    bindingContext) {
        if (ko.isObservable(allBindingAccessor().value)) {
            $(element).change(function () {
                //invert it because called before the class is added/removed :(
                allBindingAccessor().value(!$(element).hasClass("active")); 
            });
        }
        allBindingAccessor().value($(element).hasClass("active")); //init value
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
       data-bind="bootstrapCheckbox: true, value: cb1">
    <input type="checkbox" />Checkbox 1
</label>
```

Then keep the code from the first part of this answer (the subscribe).

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/H7Js6/1/)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. When you click on the checkbox, Bootstrap doesn't actually change the state of the checkbox to "checked". It just adds the "active" css class to the label surrounding the checkbox, making the appearance of the checkbox button pressed in. If I used a standard checkbox then your answer would work. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem? Did you put the data-bind on the input? This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/A4BnD/

Comment: Please have a look here, this is how it should look. You will see that the checked binding doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/H7Js6/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :) I was busy writing my own custom binding when I just saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding there's already a good answer and trying to get how it was done I thought of using the already existing click binding for this, which may be another option (not saying it's better at all)

```
var vm = function(){
    this.checkedButtons = ko.observableArray([]);    

    this.isActive =  function(item, event){
        if (!$(event.target).hasClass("active")){
            this.checkedButtons.push(event.target);
        }
        else{
            this.checkedButtons.pop();
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Usage:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label id="label1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: isActive"><input id="input1" type="checkbox">Checkbox 1</label>
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: isActive"><input type="checkbox">Checkbox 2</label>
     <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: isActive"><input type="checkbox">Checkbox 3</label>
</div>
<div>How many buttons are clicked?
    <span data-bind="text: checkedButtons().length "></span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HL9pH/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery, you can bind change event on the radio buttons themselves

```
$(".btn-group input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function(){
//you can do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap button checkboxes, which don't actually change the state of the checkbox, they just add a "active" class to the label surrounding the checkbox.

Comment: Well, I have just tried it and it's working fine. Are you sure it's not working?

Comment: Absolutely sure. Firstly, i am using Knockout to bind elements on my form. Secondly, i am using bootstrap's button checkboxes which don't work the same way that normal checkboxes work. http://jsfiddle.net/H7Js6/